# Hibernate search boolean filter

Tags: lucene, hibernate-search

I have book entry:

```
@Entity
@Indexed 
public class Book extends BaseEntity {
@Field
private String subtitle;

@DateBridge(resolution = Resolution.DAY)
private Date publicationDate;
@Field
private int score;
@IndexedEmbedded
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@Cascade(value = {CascadeType.ALL})
private List<Author> authors = new ArrayList<Author>();
@Field
@FieldBridge(impl = BooleanBridge.class)
private boolean prohibited;
```

And filter by boolean field "phohibited"

```
public class BFilter extends Filter {

@Override
public DocIdSet getDocIdSet(IndexReader indexReader) throws IOException {
    OpenBitSet bitSet = new OpenBitSet(indexReader.maxDoc());
    TermDocs termDocs = indexReader.termDocs(new Term("prohibited","false"));
    while (termDocs.next()) {
        bitSet.set(termDocs.doc());
    }
    return bitSet;
}
}
```

Search method

```
public List<T> findByQuery(Class c, String q) throws InterruptedException {
    FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(session);
    fullTextSession.createIndexer().startAndWait();

    QueryBuilder qb = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(c).get();

    Query luceneQuery = qb
            .keyword()
            .fuzzy()
            .onFields("title", "subtitle", "authors.name", "prohibited", "score")
            .matching(q)
            .createQuery();

    FullTextQuery createFullTextQuery = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery,      Book.class, BaseEntity.class);
    createFullTextQuery.setFilter(new BFilter());

    return createFullTextQuery.list();
}
```

if I apply that filter - search result is empty. Entries in the database 100% there. What am I doing wrong? If you replace the filter field to "score" that all works, and the result is not empty. Do not search it on a Boolean field

Answer (score 0):

The basic approach looks ok. A couple of comments. You are calling the indexer for each *findByQuery* call. Not sure whether this is just some test code, but you should index before you search and only once or when things change (you can also use automatic index updates). It might also be that depending on your transaction setup, your search cannot see the indexed data. However, you seem to say that all works if you don't use a filter at all. In this case I would add some debug to the filter or debug it to see what's going on and if it gets called at all. Last but not least, you don't need to explicitly set explicitly `@FieldBridge(impl = BooleanBridge.class)`.